# How generate ChangelogFile by comparing two existing changelog files

Tags: liquibase

I am using Liquibase tool to maintain versions of a database in MySQL server

Here, I generate changeLogFile for a database

After one week, I want to compare the existing changeLogFile with the same database.

Here, I need to get what are the changes made in the database for last week.

or

Is it possible to compare two changeLogFiles?

Comment: You can do what you described with liquibase. But read the [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html) for the `diff` command (same for `diffChangeLog`). 
It's of course also possible to compare 2 changelog files. But what is your question?

Comment: As per document, diff command compares two databases.

Comment: As per document, I know that diff command compares two databases. But I dont know that how to compare two changelog files using diff. could you please share the command for this.

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I get the question. You are asking if liquibase can compare two changeLog files? As far as I know: No.