# liquibase diffchange log issue repeats the change set

Tags: liquibase

Hi I am facing one issue with diffChangelog.I have performed diffchangelog between two MSSQL databases I got list of change sets.I got following

changeSet author="deekshith (generated)" id="1415884590690-1734">

modifyDataType columnName="lingo_id" newDataType="char(36)" tableName="lingo"/>

addNotNullConstraint columnDataType="char(36)" columnName="lingo_id" tableName="lingo"/>

/changeSet

I have update the change sets to respective database and again performed diffChangelog I got same as above again

changeSet author="deekshith (generated)" id="1415884590690-1736">

modifyDataType columnName="lingo_id" newDataType="char(36)" tableName="lingo"/>

addNotNullConstraint columnDataType="char(36)" columnName="lingo_id" tableName="lingo"/>

/changeSet

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: When submitting a question, it is useful to include 3 things:
- this is what I did (in as much detail as needed)
- this is what actually happened
- this is what I expected to happen
Your question doesn't have the third part.

Comment: Yes thanks steve for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mis-understanding what the Liquibase diffChangeLog command does. If you are running it between 2 databases, changing the changelog won't alter the output - what the command does is ***generate*** a changelog that you could then use with the Liquibase update command to bring the second database in sync with the first. Any changelog you already have isn't used when running the diffChangeLog command.

Comment: I have done the following tasks1.Performed liquibase diffchangelog between updated mssql database1 & database2
2 Got set of change sets and ran this against database2.
3.Repeated the step1 once again but this time got same set change sets instead of empty xml file

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185367/how-generate-changelogfile-by-comparing-two-existing-changelog-files