# liquibase compare two changelog files

Tags: xml-parsing, liquibase

I Have done the following

1. Generated Chnagelog for reference database
2. Next Generated Changelog for target database

I am expecting the following

liquibase should compare this two changelog files and give me the updates

Please let me know if we can do it using liquibase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are wanting to do isn't really possible right now. See this question.

[How generate ChangelogFile by comparing two existing changelog files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185367/how-generate-changelogfile-by-comparing-two-existing-changelog-files?rq=1)

You should be able to run liquibase diffChangeLog though to compare the two databases directly. If you cannot connect to both databases at the same time, you won't be able to use that technique though. I think the Liquibase developers are working on that capability though.